# How to get name of facebook application page?

Tags: php, facebook

How do i get a name for my application page on facebook?

Currently it like this 
https://www.facebook.com/apps/application.php?id=194769963895390

I want it to be like

https://www.facebook.com/myapp

I have 25 likes for the page,I tried facebook.com/username but it showed me my page list and not the application page list.

Answer (score 1):

type in browser address bar: http://www.facebook.com/username then you will be asked for the username for your application

Comment: The problem is its not showing the list of my application,only pages

Answer (score 0):

Facebook is currently in the process of removing app profile pages. Instead it is giving an option to migrate to an existing Facebook page. You will be able to see this as a banner on the app profile page if you are an admin. This migration will also transfer the likes to this page.

After this migration, the new page can be given a username at http://facebook.com/username

See [this post](https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/611/) on the developer blog for more information.