# Facebook OpenGraph - Liking a URL on website leads to Liking the App instead of the Facebook Fan page

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-like

Recently, I used Like Social Plugin from Facebook on my website.

I also embedded Facebook Opengraph Meta Tags on the webpage.

In OG Meta Tags, I have filled the APP ID of the dummy application i created using the same account as the Facebook Fan Page. Hence, When a visitor likes a url or post on my website, He automatically likes the Facebook App. This works perfectly.

But, I want it this way:

When a user likes a post, He must also like the Facebook Fan Page so that the like count of Fan Page increases.

Please let me know how to do this.

Answer (score 0):

Kenh,
I have my fb app: myapp.com
at the beginning I **did not** put meta tags with app id, then I have 27 likes for http://myapp.com
then I switched **https**://myapp.com then I have 7 likes
finally I succeed to put meta tag with app I have 100 likes.

The result:

- 27  likes for http://myapp.com
- 7   likes for https://myapp.com
- 100 likes for myapp.com (as application)

So you should choose one.

**EDIT**

1- this  [How to get name of facebook application page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7831429/how-to-get-name-of-facebook-application-page/7831702#7831702) Q&A may be related about your question, should wait and see

2- @Kenh says: Your page will appear in the "Likes and Interests" section of the user's profile, and you have the ability to publish updates to the user

That's correct myapp is displayed in users profile who like myapp.com in  `"Likes and Interests" section`

Comment: I created a dummy app just to test. I want visitors to automatically like the page instead of App. On Facebook Developers page for Social Plugin (LIKE Plugin)

Comment: Facebook Says :  If you include Open Graph tags on your Web page, your page becomes equivalent to a Facebook page. This means when a user clicks a Like button on your page, a connection is made between your page and the user. Your page will appear in the "Likes and Interests" section of the user's profile, and you have the ability to publish updates to the user.

Comment: What should i include in Opengraph Meta tags so that My Facebook Page for Website gets liked when a Post on my website is liked.