# How to migrate an Open Graph Page to a Business Page?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-opengraph

I have implemented the like button on a website. People have liked the website, and I have the option to administer that open graph object. However, on the administration page I see the following notice:

> Administer Your Page
>
> This is the administration interface for your
> webpage at [...]. You can see Insights and
> publish to the users that have liked your webpage. Only the
> administrators of the webpage can view this interface, other users are
> sent to the webpage.

This is a ghost page, because, as the notice says, only the administrator(s) can see it. I don't want the behavior of users being sent to my website. I want them to be able to stay on Facebook and see this page, just like they would see and interact with another business page.

Is there a tool or a request form to do this kind of migration (i.e. from an open graph page to a normal business page)?

I have researched for about two days for this issue, but I have not found any leads.

Comment: For official sources, it would be a good idea to post this on the Facebook developer group also, if you haven't already.

Comment: @bool.dev Facebook developer group? If you mean the dev forums, it is deprecated now in favor of SO. otherwise, please let me know what you meant.

Comment: No i meant the group that's on Facebook, for Facebook developers, http://www.facebook.com/groups/fbdevelopers/

Comment: @bool.dev Yeah I knew about that one, too. However, it says it right there _"[t]his is not a forum for asking technical questions, use http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/."_

Comment: no you can ask such questions, infact someone had asked a question about migrating pages sometime back, but it was not for a website, but from an old Facebook page to a new Facebook page. There was a merge option before, it's not there anymore. Anyway, your requirement is different, you will definitely get some help there. Your question is not very technical, so you can definitely ask question there.

Comment: If you looking for answer from official sources asking same question on Quora with link to SO will be better idea than asking in any Facebook group

Comment: @JuicyScripter I had no idea about Quora. If you meant quora.com, I tried to sign up, but I get _"[s]orry, you must have an invitation to create an account on Quora." If you can send any at the email address mail at my username dot me, I would appreciate it.

Comment: Hi Shef, did you manage to get anywhere with this? I have the exact same problem and haven't been able to find out anything!

Comment: @swaterfall Nope, I didn't get anywhere with it actually. I just created a new Facebook business page. The old page is still there, but it's totally dead like a nuclear waste, because no one can reach it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [this help article](https://www.facebook.com/help/?faq=249601088403018), you can merge two facebook pages into one. But the constraint is that you can merge to a page with higher likes only, and the page with fewer likes will be removed. I am not sure if it works for ghost pages or not.

Comment: +1. This is a helpful piece of information, thanks! I am still waiting for any leads, that others might have.

Comment: Although this was not the answer I was expecting, I am accepting your answer, because you did give me a hint with the merge article. However, I am thankful to others who helped, too.

Comment: Hey, but what happen after the migration to the ghost page? in case the ghost page (i.e. redirects to the real page) has the more likes - is that means that now even the merged page also redirects?!

Comment: @Yaniv Sorry for the so late reply. I migrated the ghost page (old open graph website object) to the new business page. Not the other way around. If you would do it the other way around, I am guessing it would still redirect where it was redirecting.

It doesn't redirect anymore the way I did it.

Answer (score 1):

Shef, let me try to answer:

if you have an app myapp, that is canvas url https://apps.facebook.com/myapp
then you will have an application profile page: http://www.facebook.com/myapp [*]

So if a search your app from google or facebook, then they come to first this page,
and if they click `go to app`, they reach to your app.

However if you have just implemented `like url`: myapp.com/myitem=1
then you will have this "ghost" page. You need this `ghost page`, because you need somewhere
to administrate your `likes`

So you are asking a real page instead ghost, well this is hard to implement this request by facebook guys. Because there is like link to refer some url. So there must be some pop up asking user: 'Do you want to follow link or go to business page instead'

[*] username is not available anymore for facebook apps. see [How to get name of facebook application page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7831429/how-to-get-name-of-facebook-application-page)

Comment: +1. Thanks for your answer. I am not asking about an application. Yes, I have a "link url", basically I implemented the [Open Graph](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/) when it came out. I do know that I need the administration section to administer the likes. However, all I want is for the users to be able to see this page, too. Instead of being redirected to my website when they visit _facebook.com/the_username_of_my_website_ they should stay on that page and be able to interact with it. Doesn't seem much hard to be implemented with a redirect opt-in/out for administrators.

Comment: No, it's not the `canonical url` issue. I think you are not getting me. If you [create a Business Page on Facebook](https://www.facebook.com/pages/create.php) there is a different behavior for users than if a page is created for you when an Open Graph object is liked by the administrator on a website. Once a page is created with the first method, the users will be able to visit it on Facebook itself, on the contrary if they try to visit a page created with the second method they will be redirected to the website of the Open Graph object.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `ref` parameter while specifying your like button. This ref parameter will be set by Facebook, for all url's/links that appear on Facebook, i.e wherever this like action is displayed with the link to the url liked by the user. So you know when a user visits your page through Facebook. Check the following from [this link](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/):

> ref - a label for tracking referrals; must be less than 50 characters and can contain alphanumeric characters and some punctuation (currently +/=-.:_). The ref attribute causes two parameters to be added to the referrer URL when a user clicks a link from a stream story about a Like action:
>   fb_ref - the ref parameter
>   fb_source - the stream type ('home', 'profile', 'search', 'other') in which the click occurred and the story type ('oneline' or 'multiline'), concatenated with an underscore.

Upon calling your url you can redirect the user to the page on Facebook that you want. Business pages on Facebook have a particular url, of course, and you can easily do the redirect.

I **don't think that you have an option to migrate an open graph page to a normal business page.** You can however create your page, and give it the same name as your website. The **draw back** here would be when users like your page on Facebook, you won't be able to accumulate the likes already garnered by your website.

**EDIT**
Take a look at the like box plugin (Facebook doc [here](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like-box/) ). It can be used to like pages that are on Facebook itself, from external websites. This way you will be able to accumulate your likes. You can also modify the plugin to look like a like button, not fully but almost. But you still end up creating a new page. And the old likes will not be available.

Comment: I know about the `ref`. I can also use the like button to like a business page on Facebook. I wanted to migrate my current social graph page, because if I created a new Facebook business page I would lose my current fans and chosen username.

Comment: Yeah, i had guessed that, that's why you want to migrate, which i don't think is possible. If you don't get a migration option, i would suggest, tell your current users that you have a Facebook page now, or that you have changed your name, and ask them to like the new page/name, and slowly migrate the users to the new name/brand/page/app.

Comment: +1 for the effort. Thanks. That's what I am thinking of doing right now. I will wait to see if there is any tiny chance for this to be resolved with migration, until the bounty is over.